# jQuery doesn't work on Firefox but works on Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cross-browser

I have this `jQuery` code:

```
function action(action){
    event.preventDefault();
    var products = $("#check-list input:checkbox:checked").map(function(){
      return $(this).val();
    }).get();
    var string = JSON.stringify(products);
    var table = $('#table').val();

    if(products.length != '0' || action === 'old-all'){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'app/toolbar.php',
            data: {action:action, table:table, ids:string},
            success:function(data){
                localStorage.setItem('notify', data);
                location.reload();
            },
        });
    } else{
        notify('You must choose an element first');
    }
}
```

I'm using `jQuery 3.3.1`.

If i click a button without checking a checkbox i should get `You must choose an element first` but if i choose an element the `toolbar.php` should run and do the thing it has to be done(according to which button was pressed:

```
<button class="grey-btn" onClick="action('delete')">Delete</button>
<button class="grey-btn" onClick="action('update')">Update</button>
```

It works on `Chrome` perfectly but it doesn't work on `Firefox`. I was trying some answers that i found on some other similar 'works on chrome but not on firefox' questions but neither one of them worked :(

Comment: event is not defined

Comment: Can you share which exception are you getting in console?

Comment: @epascarello can you help me define it? X_X

Comment: @BrankVictoria the consol is empty in Firefox, no message no nothing :-s

Comment: @BrankVictoria actually i was checking again, the consol is saying:  ReferenceError: event is not defined

Comment: @emma FF doesn't implement global event object, and calling `preventDefault` of an undeclared variable surely triggers an error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You do not define event so that is your problem. Get away from using inline event handlers and bind it with jQuery.

```js
$("[data-action]").on("click", function (event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var btn = $(this);
  var action = btn.data("action");
  console.log(action);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="grey-btn" data-action='delete'>Delete</button>
<button class="grey-btn" data-action='update'>Update</button>
```

If you really want to use inline event handlers than do

```js
function action (event, method) {
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log(method);
}
```

```html
<button class="grey-btn" onClick="action(event, 'delete')">Delete</button>
<button class="grey-btn" onClick="action(event, 'update')">Update</button>
```

Comment: Hey @epascarello thank youuuuuuuuuuuuuu! :D I'm going to use the inline event cause i just can't understand the other one :-s

Comment: Ahahahah... @emma... you made me laugh a lot! +1 everyone! :D

Comment: :D Well if i'm bad at jQuery at least i can make some apparently funny jokes @ReSedano :D

Comment: @emma, we're all here to improve, sooo never give up! ;)